# how to change the path to presentation in matlab?

Tags: matlab, path, powerpoint

I am new to programming in Matlab. Importing the following class: `mlreportgen.ppt.*`,the presentation is created in the current folder.
However, I would like to generate the presentation at a different location.
Found the following syntax but I am unsure of how to implement it:

```
presentationObj = Presentation() creates a presentation named Untitled.pptx in the current folder, using the default PPT API default.pptx template.

presentationObj = Presentation(presentationPath) creates a presentation at the specified location.

presentationObj = Presentation(presentationPath,templatePath) creates a presentation using the PowerPoint template at the specified location.
```

In my code, using the following to generate slides in the presentation:

```
slides = Presentation(outputFile, strcat('template_', num2str(number_of_devices))); "
where outputfile = strcat ('name','.pptx')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a full path in `outputFile` otherwise, the file will be created in the current matlab path by default.

Before creating your presentation object, just write :

```
outputfile = 'c:\path\to\your\file.pptx' (windows)
outputfile = '/path/to/your/file.pptx' (linux)
```

You can also change the current matlab folder using the command:

```
cd(newCurrentFolder)
```

You should also avoid to use `strcat` for path. `strcat`  removes trailing spaces from strings which can be sometimes problematic.  Use `cat()` or the square brackets `[str1 str2 ...]` instead.